# How to grab a particular log file and show its content in jenkins Console output

Tags: java, linux, logging, jenkins

I have the following Jenkins post-build shell script:

```
ssh user@my_server <<EOF
  service my_service stop
  service my_service start
  tail -f /opt/services/my_service/logs/current
  exit
EOF
```

This script restarts my_service on a remote host (my_server).

My problem is: command **service my_service start** just makes a request to RUNIT to run a my_service, i.e **service my_service start** returns immediately after execution.

But **service my_service start** runs a SpringBoot java web application that writes all log info into .../logs/current log file. To catch this log info I've added command **tail -f /opt/services/my_service/logs/current** but in this case Jenkins build is never ends)) such as **tail -f** command never stops.

Is there a way to execute my post-build script (which only start my web app on a remote server) and grabbing the .../logs/current log file during 2 minutes or until this log has the line "Web app MyApplication has been Started".

I wanna see the content of .../logs/current log file right in Jenkins's **Console output** and kill **tail -f** after 2 minutes

Answer (score 3):

`tail -f` will not end until it gets interrupted, so your script will never finish running.

what you can do is use `grep -q` on your log, which will exit with 0 exit status when it finds it's pattern:

```
grep -q 'Web app MyApplication has been Started' <(tail -f /opt/services/my_service/logs/current)
```

Comment: great. can i limit this command execution by 2 minutes? if deployment went wrong 'Web app MyApplication has been Started' never appears in console.